# Use rlang::env_get to evaluate a variable in the grandparent environment of the mutate call

Tags: r, rlang

I want to use `env_get` to evaluate a variable in the grandparent environment (I think) of the mutate call, but I couldn't manage. I'm describing a minimal example below.

Given a list like the following:

```
library(dplyr)

l <- list(X = 10,
        df = tibble(n = seq(-10,10), y = rnorm(21), z = runif(21)))
```

And custom mutate for these lists.

```
mutate_.list <- function(.data, ...){
    mutate_(.data$df, ...)
}
```

I want a function that can be run inside the mutate and can use the value of
`X`. Something like the following which doesn't work:

```
addX <- function(x) {
    X <-  rlang::env_get(env = parent.frame(2), 'X', inherit = TRUE)
    x + X
}
```

This works as expected.

```
mutate(l, n + 1)
```

And I would like to be able to do this:

```
mutate(l, addX(n))
```

And this doesn't work. I guess I should go up parents somehow and be able to
refer to the list, but I couldn't manage. I tried to get the plausible names of the list arguments like this:

```
addX_test <- function(x) {
    print(rlang::env_names(parent.frame(1)))  
    x 
}

mutate(l, addX_test(n))
```

But I get stuff like the following:

```
[1] "~"                        ".top_env"                
[3] ".__tidyeval_data_mask__." ".env"
```

Any pointers? Is it even doable?

Answer (score 0):

Your `X` is a field inside `l`, so it's not directly visible in the corresponding environment. If you search for `l` instead, you can then access its fields.

```
addX( 1:3 )   # Error: object 'X' not found

addX_v2 <- function(x) {
  ll <- rlang::env_get(env = parent.frame(2), 'l', inherit = TRUE)
  x + ll$X
}
addX_v2( 1:3 )
# [1] 11 12 13

mutate( l, addX_v2(n) )
# # A tibble: 21 x 4
#        n      y     z `addX_v2(n)`
#    <int>  <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>
#  1   -10  0.693 0.359            0
#  2    -9 -1.43  0.378            1
#  3    -8 -0.287 0.289            2
#  4    -7 -1.27  0.149            3
# ...
```

---

In general, it's not advisable to traverse the calling stack like that, because it breaks modularity of your code and introduces non-trivial dependencies that could lead to obscure bugs. In my opinion, a better approach is to use a function generator (function that returns a function), which will effectively bind the value of `X` to the computation that uses it:

```
Xadder <- function( .list ) { function(x) {x + .list$X} }

addX_v3 <- Xadder( l )
addX_v3(1:3)
# [1] 11 12 13

mutate( l, addX_v3(n) )     # Works as expected
```

Note that this version is more robust to a name change for your list, because it no longer searches for `l` directly.

Comment: mmh, `v2` is not very useful, because the user can name the list whatever they want, and instead of `v3` I might as well have `add_X` that takes as an argument the list as well. Would it be possible to access to an attribute of `l$df` from `addX`? If I have something like `attributes(l$df)$X <- 10`  (`l` should still be a list because in my real case, I have much more going on), is there any way that `env_get` would let me access to this attribute of `df`?

Comment: @Bruno I guess I'm a bit confused about your high-level intent. Yes, the user can change variable names, which is exactly why my answer discourages the usage of `env_get()`. R has [lexical scoping](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/scoping-rules-of-r.html), meaning functions are scoped to where they are defined, not where they are called. If the goal is to allow access to `X` from within `addX`, then you need a common environment for both, which is what `Xadder` above creates. If that's not the goal, then you need to clarify what you're trying to accomplish.